# Calculating the average with Limited memory and without using the count

Tags: average, means

I am having a flow of numbers on an embedded device, and I cannot store the flow of numbers and would like to calculate the average.

I have checked around and found one way was to do like this :
$$
Avg=  \frac{(N \times AvgOld) + NewValue }{N+1}
$$
The issue I have with the above method is that I need to calculate the `(N x AvgOld)` which by the time shall overflow (I dont have a solution for the overflow)

So I have tried another method :

$$
Avg= \frac{AvgOld+ NewValue}{2}
$$

For wich I discovered the disadvantage of being highly affected by the latest value.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ denote the average of the first $n$ values of the sequence $\{Y_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. In order to avoid the overflow problem you could try to calculate as following
$$
X_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}(nX_n + Y_{n+1}) = \frac{n}{n+1}X_n + \frac{1}{n+1}Y_{n+1}.
$$
By splitting like this you avoid the very big number $nX_n$, because you divide by $n+1$ first.

Note that if the numbers come from some distibution then one can possibly apply a law of large numbers, to deduce that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n$ exists and thus that after a certain point, updating the average changes the result very little.

Comment: Thank you a lot Marc, I really appreciate your answer. Kindly Find some questions below: 
1- If you consider I am doing my calculations on a microcontroller not supporting Floating Point unit,
    so for some time I will have a problem of either the division results into a zero or the multiplication results in an overflow
    
2- What about my calculation of X_(n+1) = (X_(n) + Y_(n+1) ) /2 Does it have a scientific name?, How far is its error from the Average ?

Thanks again

Comment: The more observations you add, the less impact the next observation should have, since $1/(n+1)\rightarrow 0$. Therefore, giving it fixed weight of 0.5 will not necessarily be close to the actual average.